# Shrink plain Java library with ProGuard within Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, proguard

I use Gradle and I want to shrink a library with ProGuard. This looks easy: just add ProGuard to buildscript's classpath and create ProGuard task ([example](https://github.com/facebook/proguard/blob/master/examples/gradle/library.gradle)).

I will get a new jar then, but if i write `compile project(':library')` in another module or execute `:library:bintrayUpload` task, old jar still will be used.

How can I shrink library jar **before** Gradle takes it and passes further, as a dependency or to Bintray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there's a `proguard` task.

```
def libraryJar = rootProject.file(
        "${project.name}/build/libs/${project.name}-${project.version}.jar")
def shrinkedJar = rootProject.file(
        "${project.name}/build/libs/${project.name}-${project.version}-shrinked.jar")

jar.finalizedBy proguard
proguard.doLast {
    if (!libraryJar.delete()) throw new IllegalStateException()
    if (!shrinkedJar.renameTo(libraryJar)) throw new IllegalStateException()
}
```

That's it!